# Autofill service not populating user info into a form within a webview in my app

Tags: android, webview

I looked at several issues and was unable to find one that matched mine; apologies ahead of time if I missed it!

I have a native app, a portion of which contains a webview.  The webview leads to a page that has a login.  When going to the login form android autofill suggestions will pop up and upon selecting them the login process "appears" to initiate however, I'm not actually seeing my onSubmit function firing from the page contained within the webview and ultimately the page returns to the login page as the user is not actually authed.  I'm also not seeing the user items populated in the contained webpages state.

Any ideas on why the autofill items are not populating in the form within the webview?  Any other things I can try to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case, I was actually changing the webview's HTML in the onPause() lifecycle event to ensure the webview stopped hitting our backend; something that was creating incorrect usage stats.  This functionality should actually have been placed in the onStop() as it is:

1. The behavior I actually wanted as I only needed to change the HTML when my app is not visible to the user.
2. The autofill service triggers onPause() thus making it so the HTML would be changed when the app was still visible and thus, the HTML android was trying to autofill was no longer present.